# Filter page search logic

Tags: search, filter, search-results, data-tables

Good day,

I'm currently rethinking some current implementations of our search screens.
Right now we've got datagrids with large amounts of data.

[image]

With these datagrids the only option right now is filtering the results with all the inputs shown above. For instance, when users search for a specific date they get the resulted dates in return.

I am thinking that the number of filters is overkill, because the user should be limited in the initial search. Filtering with all filters or a large amount of filters is not going to happen very often, so is really an edge case.

In my opinion i would love to give the user the main search filters as a base search, and when clicking on advanced filtering the other filters will be shown.

In this case the user isn't confused by the large amount of filters available and the search goal is achieved more easily.

Hope yo hear what you all think about this matter.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a google like search box that searches across all columns?

Comment: it's a pretty high amount of data that can be retrieved, but also really specific data. So i think that is not the best option.

Comment: Could update your screenshot with a version without the blank speace, please.

Answer (score 1):

I am aligned with you and I would suggest:

- Provide a search input with basic parameters
- Provide "Advanced Search" options (show / hide on click)
- Providing basic and advanced search filters not only narrows down the search results, but it also improves the overall performance of the app when you have huge data.
- Finally, based on the options selected (search criteria) in basic and/or advanced search, provide the "Facets" which gives the ability for the users to narrow down the search results further down.